# handful of busy threads vs. many mostly-idle threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, concurrency

i've got some code where for each User object, 1-2 seconds of work is done, then wait 60 seconds, then do more work. My question is if i have lets say a few thousand Users, aside for more memory for stacks for each thread, is there any other downside to having one thread per User (sleeping during the 60s wait), as opposed to having a far smaller number of threads service all the Users?

Comment: Regardless of the overhead, what's the upside?  You can probably do the same thing as easily with a limited thread pool, a queue, and a system timer.  Aren't you going to need cond vars or whatnot to wake these thousands of threads anyway?

Comment: actually i have it coded and working in production with the queue & threadpool already, i'm just worried about contention on q's mutex, and for some reason load goes up with less threads even tho cpu usage stays the same, which i just dont understand at all..

Comment: What do you mean by load in this context?

Comment: 'load average' from top

Answer (score 0):

aside from memory limits you may hit some limits like `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` and `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count` but otherwise it should be ok. There might be other small related overheads but why not if it works for you and you don't expect increase in load so that you exhaust the machine resources. I mean why fix if you don't have a problem?

It's a good idea, no matter which approach you take to see how machine behaves with the anticipated upper limit of concurrent users and make sure it has some headroom for unexpected situations.